# Veracrypt Win10 Opening drive from container fails with error location not avaiable

Tags: veracrypt

I am having an issue with veracrpt on my Win 10 1809 machine. When I mount an encrypted container, I get an error:

[image]

I have tried using an existing container that loads fine on my MacBook, and I also tried creating a new container on the Win 10 machine and that failed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was occurring because I was using Bootcamp on Win10 and the Apple HFS drivers were causing the issue. Removing them resolved this.